# Como desabilitar e habilitar um adaptador de rede com o Delphi?

Tags: delphi, redes

Tenho uma aplicação que a certo momento deve desabilitar e habilitar o adaptador de rede do Windows, pesquisei pela internet, mas não encontrei nada.

Teste antes de postar uma resposta porque informações duvidosas só atrasam o meu trabalho.

Comment: Acredito que WMI é um caminho mais fácil a seguir, se performance não for tão necessária pra você. Não que WMI seja lento, mas... é mais lento que trabalhar com a interface de rede via WINAPI clássica. A classe em questão é [essa](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh968170(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: Conseguiu resolver @Pascal?

Comment: @PascalStarting se consegui ajudar com a minha resposta, pode aceitar a resposta clicando no ✔ no lado esquerdo da mesma. Se necessitar de alguma mais ajuda avise

Answer (score 3):

Através do seguinte código é possível **habilitar** e **desabilitar** uma placa de rede há escolha, enviando comandos para a linha de comandos e tratando o seu output, tentei detalhar tudo o que acontece no código para perceber os passos:

```
Procedure TfrmMain.ResetNetwork;
var i, APos: Integer;
    ALine, AIndex, AName: String;
begin
  //pega todas as redes do pc
  Memo1.Text := Memo1.Text + GetDosOutput('wmic nic get name, index');
  Application.ProcessMessages;

  //vai ler todas linhas do memo uma a uma
  for i := 0 to Memo1.Lines.Count - 1 do
    Begin
      //passa a linha para uma variavel
      //exemplo da linha pretendida:
      //"0      Microsoft Kernel Debug Network Adapter"
      ALine := AnsiUpperCase(Memo1.Lines[i]);    

      //pega o valor "index 
      APos := Pos(' ', ALine);
      if (APos > 0) then
        begin
          AIndex := Trim(AnsiMidStr(ALine, 1, APos - 1));
          Delete(ALine, 1, APos);
        end;

      //verifica se o valor "name" é igual ao pretendido
      if AnsiLeftStr(Trim(ALine), 38) = 'MICROSOFT KERNEL DEBUG NETWORK ADAPTER' then
        Begin
          //se o valor for igual passa aqui
          Memo1.Lines.Add('DISABLE index: ' + AIndex);
          //aqui desabilita
          GetDosOutput('wmic path win32_networkadapter where index='+ AIndex +' call disable');
          Application.ProcessMessages;
          sleep(2000);
          Memo1.Lines.Add('ENABLE index: ' + AIndex);
          //aqui habilita
          GetDosOutput('wmic path win32_networkadapter where index='+ AIndex +' call enable');
          Application.ProcessMessages;
        End;
    End;
End;

Function TfrmMain.GetDosOutput(CommandLine: string; Work: string = 'C:\'): string;
var SA: TSecurityAttributes;
    SI: TStartupInfo;
    PI: TProcessInformation;
    StdOutPipeRead, StdOutPipeWrite: THandle;
    WasOK: Boolean;
    Buffer: array[0..255] of AnsiChar;
    BytesRead: Cardinal;
    WorkDir: string;
    Handle: Boolean;
begin
  Result := '';
  with SA do
    begin
      nLength := SizeOf(SA);
      bInheritHandle := True;
      lpSecurityDescriptor := nil;
    end;
  CreatePipe(StdOutPipeRead, StdOutPipeWrite, @SA, 0);
  try
    with SI do
      begin
        FillChar(SI, SizeOf(SI), 0);
        cb := SizeOf(SI);
        dwFlags := STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW or STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;
        wShowWindow := SW_HIDE;
        hStdInput := GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE); // don't redirect stdin
        hStdOutput := StdOutPipeWrite;
        hStdError := StdOutPipeWrite;
      end;
    WorkDir := Work;
    Handle := CreateProcess(nil, PChar('cmd.exe /C ' + CommandLine), nil, nil, True, 0, nil, PChar(WorkDir), SI, PI);
    CloseHandle(StdOutPipeWrite);
    if Handle then
      try
        repeat
          WasOK := ReadFile(StdOutPipeRead, Buffer, 255, BytesRead, nil);
          if BytesRead > 0 then
            begin
              Buffer[BytesRead] := #0;
              Result := Result + Buffer;
            end;
        until not WasOK or (BytesRead = 0);
        WaitForSingleObject(PI.hProcess, INFINITE);
      finally
        CloseHandle(PI.hThread);
        CloseHandle(PI.hProcess);
      end;
  finally
    CloseHandle(StdOutPipeRead);
  end;
end;
```